# How to communicate mysql & mysqladmin docker containers

Tags: docker

I want to spawn MySQL & PHPMyAdmin docker containers. Mysql container can be accessed via 3306 port & PHPMyAdmin can be accessed through 8280 port.

My question is, how a PHP application can be configured to access the MySQL docker container on 3306 port
and the PHPMyAdmin can be configured for MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: I have been gone through https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql but it did not help me in this case.

Comment: Probably best way is to create a docker-compose file that includes both images. However, you need to connect them to the same network. More info can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Comment: Thanks @FarzadVertigo

Answer (score 1):

Start MySQL server

```
docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql
```

Start phpAdmin with link to mysql container

```
docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql:db -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

PHPAdmin application will be serving on localhost:80. MySQL credentials will be root/password.

We can now use docker-compose for this solution which is more portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the offical image for MySQL and PHPMyAdmin.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8081:80
```

To access it from php container, just add your php container in the docker-compose, so the connection string should be like

```
host:db
user: root
pass: example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adminer a database management tool.

You need the below configuration in docker-compose.yml for Mysql and adminer.

```
 mysqldb:
  container_name: mysqldb
  image: mysql
  restart: always
  environment:
  - MYSQL_USER= 'xyz'
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD='pwd0123456789'
  - MYSQL_DB= 'testdb'
networks:
  - main

adminer: 
 container_name: adminer
 image: adminer
 restart: always
 ports:
  - 4041:8080
 networks:
  - main-network
 depends_on:
  - mysqldb
```

Comment: To access adminer use the following configuration as per the above docker-compose.yml file. 
URL : http://domain:4041
"system:"MySQL', "Server":"mysqldb","username":"xyz", "password":"pwd0123456789', "Database":"testdb"